# Get the VBProject of a Database

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbe

Given a database object in MS Access VBA, how can one get that database's VBProject?

```
Function GetVBProject(ByVal db As Database) As VBProject
    Set GetVBProject = ???
End Function
```

The only way I know how to get VBProjects in Access is through `Application.VBE.VBProjects.Item(???)`.  However, I won't know what order of the projects are in and what the name is.  I will only know it's parent database. The equivalent in Excel would be simply

```
Function GetVBProject(ByVal wb As Workbook) As VBProject
    Set GetVBProject = wb.VBProject
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the `VBProjects` collection and check each project's `FileName` property.  If a project's `FileName` is the current database file (`CurrentDb.Name`), that is the one you want.

```vb
Public Function ThisProject() As String
    Dim objVBProject As Object
    Dim strReturn As String
    For Each objVBProject In Application.VBE.VBProjects
        If objVBProject.FileName = CurrentDb.Name Then
            strReturn = objVBProject.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ThisProject = strReturn
End Function
```

That function returns the project name.  You could use the name to set a reference to the `VBProject` object.  Or you could revise the function to return the `VBProject` instead of a string.

I barely tested this, so I'm uncertain `objVBProject.FileName = CurrentDb.Name` will be the correct test condition for every situation.  But I hope this answer gives you something useful to build on.

I looked into `objVBProject.FileName` vs. `CurrentDb.Name` when the db is opened from a drive letter and from a UNC path to a network share.  Either way, it seems `objVBProject.FileName` and `CurrentDb.Name` both "self-adjust" and still match each other:

```vb
' db opened from a drive letter ...
? CurrentDb.Name
C:\share\Access\BigDb_secure.mdb
? application.VBE.VBProjects("BigDb_secure").FileName
C:\share\Access\BigDb_secure.mdb

' db opened from UNC path to network share ...
? CurrentDb.Name
\\HP64\share\Access\BigDb_secure.mdb
? application.VBE.VBProjects("BigDb_secure").FileName
\\HP64\share\Access\BigDb_secure.mdb
```

Comment: Using the filename. Smart. ++

Comment: It won't be correct if the Access file is on a relative path.  `CurrentDb.Name` will use the drive letter for a mapped drive but `VBProject.FileName` will return the network path.

Comment: @cheezsteak Not sure what you meant by relative path.  Are you talking about something different from the test cases I added to the answer?

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I didn't expect it to behave differently with a samba share.  In that case I suppose you could check whether `Dir(...FileName)` matches `Dir(CurrentDB.Name)`  That would only break if you had another project reference to a db file whose name matches the name of the current db.

Answer (score 4):

It may be kind of late to answer this but if it is the current project you want to address then

```
Set vbProj = VBE.ActiveVBProject
```

will work.